# Asp.Net Web Api -- OData Query => ComosDb Query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, odata, azure-cosmosdb

I'm building an Asp.Net Web API, which I plan to have conform to ODATA query standard, and backed by Cosmos Db.

Lets looks at a generic workflow I'm looking for help solving:

Model:

```
Vehicle {
    public int NoWheels {get;set;}
    public string Type {get;set;}
}
```

ODATA Query:

```
/api/Vehicle?$filter=NoWheels+eq+4&Type+eq+'Sedan'
```

DocumentDb Query:

```
SELECT * FROM v WHERE v.NoWheels=4 AND v.Type='Sedan'
```

Now I'm tasked with, **1.** Translating the Query String into a manageable object to infer what the Client has requested, and **2.** Use that object to form a DocumentDb query.

What I'm wondering is do I need to reinvent the wheel? I have noticed some nuget packages at my disposal ([Microsoft.AspNet.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/), [Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Odata.Sql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.OData.Sql/)) but I have some reservations. For 1, all articles mentioning [Microsoft.AspNet.OData](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.OData/), suggest using EF. For 2, [Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Odata.Sql](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Documents.OData.Sql/) is not widely used, and not officially delivered by Microsoft. I know that I can manually take the `Request.QueryString` to make the translation from url to an OData Object, and then use that Object to construct my DocumentDb query, but I'm curious if this problem has already been solved, or at the very least, if there are pieces that have been solved and I can leverage.

With all that being said, does anyone have experience working with Asp.Net + DocumentDb + OData? If so, how did you handle this problem?

Comment: i would recommend you to use the odata query Parser from Microsoft and build the queries yourself. You dont need EF. Here https://github.com/OData/odata.net/blob/master/README.md

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? I am facing the exact same issue

Comment: I ended up using https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData/7.0.0-beta2 to handle the ODATA query

Comment: @David.Jones Can you provide your solution as an answer to this question?